# Targeting something which has the same class as something else with css

Tags: html, css

I'd like to target a button which seems to have the same class as another button. Is there a way to differenciate using css when I can't change the html?

On this  [page](https://adsler.co.uk/create-account/) the submit button has disappeared but I think it's because I've hidden a button which shares the same class [here](https://adsler.co.uk)

Html:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn button ur-submit- 
button">
<span></span>Submit</button>
```

Comment: css allows nested class selectors so if your form has a ID then you can do something along the lines of #formID .ur-submit- 
button {}

Comment: Thanks but it doesn't and I can't add one. :-(

Comment: Post a scaled down example of the html structure of the form. In its current state, it is impossible to help you.

Comment: Your `body` element seems to have quite a few different classes identifying the page, could you use one of those to hide the submit button only on that page?

eg. `.page-id-19 .ur-submit-button {...}`

Comment: There are at least three different ways to do this based on using something like `button:not([type="submit"])` or `button:nth-of-type(5)` or `button:not(.ur-submit-button)` but it's impossible to tell you which one without showing the CSS you're using and the HTML of the two buttons, the one you want to select and the one you don't want to select.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could see common class `.btn` having following properties:

```
.btn.btn {
    color: transparent! important;
    background: transparent! important;
    border: none! important;
}
```

Try adding your class selector which is `.ur-submit-button` to override hidden property for your class, by adding the following CSS:

```
button.btn.button.ur-submit-button {
    color: initial !important;
    /* background: initial !important; */
    /* border: initial !important; */
}
```

It will display the button and then you can further modify its look and feel using same selector.

Although usage of `!important` is not a good practice, but it seems to be already used by plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the suggestion by Travis Acton to identify a parent on your create-account page that is different from the homepage. It looks like the form on the create-account page has the class `register`, which doesn't appear to be used on the homepage.  I would try this:

```
.register .btn.ur-submit-button {
    color: black;
}
```

If you're new to CSS, "parent" just means an HTML element that contains the element you're trying to target.

Comment: Thanks. It does make sense but didnt work when I tried it.....unless something else is hiding the button?

Comment: You have a rule in .btn.btn that sets the color and background color to transparent.  Can you try adding an !important to color: black?